# how to create api with app router in next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, app-router

I have setup new next project and used the app router as next recommend this in latest version. Now I want to create the API so how can I create and use this API inside my page `app/user/page.tsx`?

I have create one API inside the `app/api/user/page.tsx` but it seems not working properly like actual it should work as API

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly you mean by "create api with app router" and include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: @DrewReese it is simple i have created a fresh next setup and there is 2 way to use page route using `app` and `page` So as per the next recommendation I have used the `app router` https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation#the-app-directory

So now I just want to create one API inside the next so how can I do this do I need to create API inside `pages/api/user.tsx`? This is right way if not please explain this!

Comment: Are you asking about how to create, or access, a ***backend*** API? API to *what*? This sort of [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)? I don't understand what you mean by "create API inside ....".

Comment: Yes want to access backend as next is the full stake and we can create and use API inside the next it self so yes I want to access backend and start development and building rest API inside the next

Comment: I see, then yes, we'll certainly need to see a [mcve] for what you are trying to do... unless you haven't actually done anything yet and you are just asking how, in which case might be considered too broad a question for StackOverflow and need to focused to a single specific topic/issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Nextjs 13 the you can create an API with the `route.ts` file.

Instead of `app/api/user/page.tsx` create a `app/api/user/route.ts`.

Also there cannot be a `route.ts` file at the same route segment level as `page.ts`.

More information on [Nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your answer! I have checked the doc as well can you please explain with an example as you mentioned line above please?

Also there cannot be a route.ts file at the same route segment level as page.ts.

Comment: > Also there cannot be a route.ts file at the same route segment level as page.ts

This basically means that there cannot be a `route.ts` **and** `page.ts` file for the same route.